# Why my nested datatable is not displaying the plus and minus signs?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables, nested-table

I have a nested data table which is not being displayed properly, it doesn't display the plus and minus sign , neither the pagination. 
It seems like I am loading some styling wrong but I cant see where. I followed a JSFiddle example which works there but when I copy it in my computer it doesn't.

```
 <head>    
       <meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            'responsive': true
        });

        // Handle click on "Expand All" button
        $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function() {
            // Expand row details
            table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
        });

        // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
        $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function() {
            // Collapse row details
            table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th class="none">Age</th>
            <th class="none">Start date</th>
            <th class="none">Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

I am new to HTML and datatables so probably I am making stupid mistake somewhere but I cant detect.

Comment: I haven't looked too closely yet but try this first: in the `head`, put the meta tags first, then your css, and js last, and add the link to jquery *before* datatables js. Try that, update your question to show the changes and let us know if it's still not working. Tnx.

Comment: @wazz didn't change much, still there is no plus or minus signs.

Comment: Your example is missing the jQuery library - for example: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` - or wherever you choose to get it (I recommend a minimized version). Put that reference first in the head section.

Comment: Also your example is missing the opening `<html>` tag - but that's probably just a copy/paste thing.

Comment: Works fine for me here.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks, that did the job!